Displaying Documentation of a lit web component
I have a simple lit web component defined and documented in typescript but the component's documentation is not showing when i hover over it in its call site.
 ...

/**
 * @description
 * MyMessage demonstrates hinting issue
 * 
 * 
 * @slot - content of the message
 * 
 * @property {string} headline - headline of the message
 * 
 */

@customElement('my-message')
export class MyMessage extends LitElement {
    static styles = [
        css`
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        `
    ];

    /**
     * Headline of the message
     * @type {string}
     */
    @property({type: String})
    headline = ""

    render() {
        return html`
            <h1>${this.headline}</h1>
            <slot name="message"></slot>
        `;
    }
}


Hovering over it when it's used in another component only shows the slot documentation while doing the same in an html file shows nothing but the tag itself.
How can I get the editor to show all the documentation. i.e description, slots and property
